# Android and BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an app that should to connect a BLE device and download all the information that this device has storage in your flash memory.

So I'm building this code:

This is the Timer that I use to download ALL the information every X minutes:

```
TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            valore = true;
            int conta = 0;
            while(valore){
                conta++;
                if (currDevice != null) {
                    mGatt = currDevice.connectGatt(getBaseContext(), false, gattClientCallback);
                }else{
                    //provo a ricollegarmi al dispositivo probabile, abbia perso la connessione con esso
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

This is the method that I use to connect at BLE device:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        //VERIFICO SE IL DEVICE è QUELLO CHE VOGLIO IO
        if (mGatt == null && settingApp != null
                && device.getAddress().equals(settingApp.getAddressBleSX())) {
            currDevice = device;
            gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
            mGatt = currDevice.connectGatt(getBaseContext(), false, gattClientCallback);
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }
```

This is the LeScanCallback():

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    Handler h = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                    // Although you need to pass an appropriate context
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //  Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                                connectToDevice(device);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
```

This the last code to effectively download data from BLE device and storage it on SqlLite

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    Handler h = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                    // Although you need to pass an appropriate context
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //  Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                                connectToDevice(device);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
           // Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
           // Log.i("result", result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = null;
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                btDevice = result.getDevice();
            }
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
               // Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
          //  Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

        @SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            try{
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                Log.i("tag", "onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
                    Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                    disconnectGattServer();
                    return;
                } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
                    Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                    disconnectGattServer();
                    return;
                }

                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    //Log.i("INFO", "Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Log.i("INFO", "Disconnected from device");
                    disconnectGattServer();
                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("ON_CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGE", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        public void disconnectGattServer() {
           valore = false;
            if (mGatt != null) {
                mGatt.disconnect();
                mGatt.close();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
             //   Log.i("INFO", "Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics =
                    BluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt,stringSequence);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
              //  Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE","Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }else{
                gatt.readCharacteristic(matchingCharacteristics.get(0));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

            SensorData mSenData = new SensorData();
                mSenData.setValue(characteristic.getStringValue(0));
                mSenData.setIdType(++id);
                mSenData.setCharacteristic(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                mSenData.setValueTimestamp(db.getDateTime());
                db.insertSensorData(mSenData);

            } else {
                Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);
            }
        }
```

Now, if I try to start my application, I can download some data from BLE device as 35, 36 values. After that I received this message from *onConnectionStateChange* method

> E/ERROR_SERVICE: Connection not GATT sucess status 128

So after this error, the timer stopped. After X minutes the method restart but I'm not able to download never error from BLE device.

So how can I download all data from BLE device every X minutes and until the BLE device have data storage in yuor memory ?

Comment: I hope your problem will be solved if you use android Job Scheduler instead of timer

Comment: Why do you have a timer that creates a BluetoothGatt object every 300 ms? That will make you run out of gatt connections pretty quick.